# Smart pointer to an object that can change the pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, smart-pointers

I want to have a smart pointer to an object `A` that has a function `f` which can change the current object `A` that the smart pointer should point to. The function should work for all smart pointers and its ideal syntax is this:

```
//usage of f
std::unique_ptr<A> p(new A);
p.reset(p->f(p.get()));
```

Raw pointers are used as argument and return value to make this work with any smart pointer. The flaw in this implementation is self-assignment caused by `f` returning the same pointer it was given. The self-assignment will result in the deletion of the current instance of `A`, which is not what we want. To remedy this we could use `f` like this:

```
//modified usage of f
std::unique_ptr<A> p(new A);
A* temp = p->f(p.get());
if(p.get() != temp) {
  p.reset(temp);
}
```

This requires a temporary raw pointer right next to the smart pointer that might even point to the same object. To me it feels like bad design and I expect there to be a better solution than this.

I've also thought about passing a the smart pointer by reference, but this has some problems:

- It does not force a return after resetting the smart pointers, which could cause memory corruption.
- It forces the function to take a specific smart pointer as argument.

Am I overthinking this problem? Is using a temporary raw pointer to check if the smart pointer needs to be reset actually fine?
Also, why does the `reset` function not already check for self-assignment?

### Clarification update

First of all, `f(p.get())` can be replaced by `f()` in the examples, since the input argument is not needed. The function will either return a pointer to itself or create a new object and return that pointer.

Thanks for all the help till now, here is a brief clarification.
Class `A` was intended to be used as a state, which has a function that is called repeatedly to handle whatever needs to be done when the program is in that state. This handling would also include possibly changing the state, which is done by returning the appropriate pointer to the new state.

I uploaded an [example and explanation](https://github.com/lukabavdaz/state_system_v1) (using raw pointers only) of how I want to use this class. Feedback on the design is welcome. Although I realize that was not the initial question, it might lead to the answer that I really seek.

Comment: Can you give some clarification about why you need to do this, and some larger context? At first glance this looks like something you ought not to need to do, and I suspect there's a better design to suit your ultimate aims.

Comment: I wanted to use `A` as a state, which has a function that is called repeatedly to handle whatever needs to be done when the program is in that state. This handling would also include possibly changing the state.

Comment: I would say the design is kind of flawed. You are using a unique_ptr to an object that has a function that mutes the pointed object A. Can you tell us more about the mutability requirement that you have? Can you provide more insight into the get function? At least the signature?

Comment: Your ideal syntax makes no sense. `A` is a type, but in your second line you are trying to do an indirect function call on it, as if it's a pointer. And in your first line, you are assigning to the type `std::unique_ptr<A>`, also nonsense.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Whoops, thank's for pointing it out. I meant to call the `f` function of the object pointed to by `p`. I will edit it.

Comment: @Elyasin I would be glad to hear if my design is flawed, and I honestly wouldn't be that surprised. The `get` function simply returns the raw pointer to the managed object and is a function all std smart pointers have. As to the mutability requirement, here is an example: `A` has a button, and if pressed the instance of `A` needs to be swithed out, so I use `return new A`. If the button is not pressed it simply returns the pointer it got in the input, since A does not need to be switched out.

Comment: When state changes, could you just modify the private data and keep the object, instead of returning a different object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to have a smart pointer to an object A that has a function f which can change the current object A that the smart pointer should point to.

This is a very strange (and awkward) Object Oriented class design. Your object has a member function which will modify the objects that owns the pointer to it. A complete redesign of your class structures is highly advised.

You should rather design this like:

- Your class `A` which does not has `f` as a member function
- A second class `B` which contains and manages the smart pointer, and has `f` as the member function

Or:

- `f` is a static function inside `A` and takes a reference to the smart pointer:

static f(shared_ptr & shPtr);

Comment: Although I'm sad to hear having an object that can let itself be replaced by creating a new object of the same type is bad design, I do understand. However, I don't understand how your design would work for me. Since class `A` will be the program state, I don't understand how `B` is supposed to know when the state should be switched (and to which state) without getting that information from `A` in some way. Also, making `f` static would unfortunately decrease the functionality of the system.

Comment: I do not know your full program, but it sounds like that the shared object should be used for storage purpose only (class A), and that the functions should be implemented outside that class (class B). The class B is the interface to the outside world, the class A is a private implementation class for storing data in a shared pointer.

Comment: I intended the function `f` to be used as a `getState()` function like you suggested, but I didn't want to use class `A` for storage only (though I will definitely take that possibility into consideration). I edited the original post to include a brief explanation and a link to the code I currently have working with raw pointers, which (I hope) clearly explains my intent with this class. If you see any way to improve the design I would love to know.

Comment: What I eventually did was introduce a second class (as you also recommended) to complete the state pattern that fits the situation naturally. One downside is that switching is not done through return value, so forgetting to return could cause memory corruption. I've also chosen to use unique pointers exclusively for states, since I've come to realize that using a shared pointer is most likely bad design here. The final code is easier to extend and (much) more readable. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use release method of std::unique_ptr:

UPDATE:

```
class A {
public:
    A* f( std::unique_ptr<A> pointer )
    {
        if( /* some condition */ ) {
            return new A;
        } else {
            return pointer.release();
        }
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<A> p( new A );
p.reset( p->f( std::unique_ptr<A>( p.release() ) ) );
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. Using release causes problems whenever `f` does not return the same pointer it was given, since the old pointer would not be cleaned up properly. Of course you could manually clean it up inside `f`, but the idea was to let the smart pointer do it for me.

Comment: thanks again for the suggestion! I'd probably use `move` instead of `release`, but this is a very good idea (don't know how I didn't come up with it...) It does however have the problem of only working with one specific smart pointer.

Comment: @LBavdaz std::move good idea only if you work with std::unique_ptr. My code above work fine with any smart pointers.

Comment: Even after changing A->f(...) to p->f(...) as I think you intended, it doesn't compile for me. The function p.release() does not return a smart pointer, which is what the function f requires.

Comment: @LBavdaz sorry, I updated code above. This is because std::unique_ptr forbid implicit conversion from A* to std::unique_ptr.